# Who (client, supplier, individual developer) should bear the costs of software code understanding/comprehension?

Tags: software-industry, contracts

I am tasked to make some minor changes in our software product. The customer thinks that changes are minor and from the business point of view the customer is right.

But the software piece (very complex suite of reports, that consists of multitude of modules with tens of parameterized SQL requests all in undocumented combination which involves on-the-fly modifications of the intermediate results and branching) is very hard to understand and comprehend, i.e. it can be said to be unmaintainable due to the lack of (at least) high level documentation which would map the business requirements to the code blocks that are responsible for them.

My question is - who should bear the costs of developer time that is devoted to the comprehension of this code and for finding the right place to make the modification of the code. It can be: 1) customer; 2) software company; 3) individual developer (who made the initial development and is gone or who is making modification now)?

Comment: As with all costs, this is what the contract is for. Did the company make any promises as to max billing for an issue/ticket? Is this a fixed price contract? Is the maintenance contract charged by billed hours, ticket count, fixed rate, ...? I'm pretty sure this is not your problem to tackle as the developer.

Answer (score 6):

You get paid your salary. Unless you are a contractor, where you get paid your daily rate for as many days as it takes - you wouldn't accept anything else in a situation like this.

Between client and company, the company needs to check if they have legal obligations, otherwise they charge the real cost plus a bit of profit. Now it is possible that the "real cost" is a lot more than the change is worth, in that case the client will go without the change.

Answer (score 6):

I would argue that the key point of dispute is not about "who pays", it is this:

> The customer thinks that changes are minor and from the business point of view the customer is right.

Saying that something *should be* easy is just wishful thinking; it is not something the customer can *control*.

I might look at a dent in a car door and say that it *should be* easy to straighten out; but if I'm not planning to straighten it myself, that's not really relevant. If a mechanic says that *that particular dent, in that particular door* will cost a certain amount to fix, I can't simply demand that it be done cheaper; I can:

- Pay the quoted price
- Get an independent quote from a different mechanic
- Attempt to negotiate a cheaper price in the hope that the mechanic will reduce their margin, or do the work at a loss in exchange for future goodwill
- Leave the dent in the door

The same applies here. The developer is only responsible for determining the *actual cost* of the change; that includes whatever additional research and refactoring is required based on the current state of the software. How the software got *into* that state is irrelevant, except for making strategic decisions on how to improve it for future changes.

The software company then enters into negotiation with the customer. Ideally, they would like to pass on the full cost, plus a healthy margin; that is their aim as a business. If the customer challenges that quote (or is likely to), they can either:

- Stand their ground. The customer can either pay the quote, do without the change, or deal with the costs of switching supplier.
- Reduce their profit, possibly below cost. The customer gets their way and is happy, but the company has lost money, which will need to be made up from later margins.

*Strategically*, the company can invest in documenting and refactoring the system so that future changes are cheaper - but again, this work is happening at a loss (zero payments for non-zero costs), so there needs to be a plan for how to recoup that loss out of future margins.

Answer (score 2):

As(if I understand you correctly) this is the software company's product that they produced originally and supply to the customer then this would be on them. They can bill the customer for a reasonable time to make the modifications overhead in terms of getting another developer up to speed to make those modifications isn't the customer's problem.

Ultimately they can probably amortize those sunk costs across future work though.

Answer (score 0):

If your company is selling software to a customer, and part of that offering is to make changes/add new features, then it's the company's responsibility to make sure that their staff have sufficient knowledge to do so. They shouldn't be paying for your developers to learn the product any more than they should be paying for your developers to lean programming skills, or the language it's written in.

> it can be said to be unmaintainable due to the lack of (at least) high level documentation which would map the business requirements to the code blocks that are responsible for them.

This is 100% a problem for your company. If they're selling badly written, undocumented and "unmaintainable" software, then it's not the customer's responsibility to deal with that.

Comment: This is simply not true. The prices charged to the customer *absolutely* need to cover the cost of hiring and training staff, otherwise the company is running at a loss, and will quickly go bankrupt. It is up to the company to keep those prices at a level the customer is willing to pay, and possibly to spread them unevenly based on customer relationships, but the customer cannot simply make up their own price based on an alternative reality where the product and team are in a different state.

Comment: Let me see if I get this right. I work for a company with five products A to E. I know everything about A, but nothing at all about B, C, D and E. So you are saying that if I asked to make changes to B the company shouldn't pay me for the time it takes me to learn B? Seriously?

Comment: If I've bought product B from you, and your company agrees to make changes to the product, then I expect them to assign that work to someone who knows product B. I don't expect to be charged for your employee's lack of knowledge about the product *that you sell*, any more than I'd expect to be charged for them learning how to program.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be: 1) customer; 2) software company;

That's a business decision. The company can try to charge the customer for their internal inefficiencies but it's likely to damage the relationship and a risk to future business.

3. individual developer (who made the initial development and is gone or who is making modification now)?

Absolutely not. That's a management mistake, not a developer one. Someone defined the tasks, its requirements, the deliverable and accepted the work as is. If the company have proper oversight over the quality of the deliverables, it's not the developers fault.

Comment: Besides, the original developer may not be available anymore (possibly dead).